# Supermicro проблема со стартом

Tags: железо

Платформа: **H8DGU-8**

Было произведено плановое обновление до последней версии BIOS и IPMI размещенных на оф. сайте supermicro.
После данной операции начались проблемы, сервер стартует ровно через 1 час. Нажимаем кнопку power, начинается загрузка и синхронизация дисков, все проходит успешно, но дальше не происходит ничего. На экран не идет изображение, клавиатура не активна, так целый час, после чего начинается загрузка в штатном режиме. IPMI то работает, то нет (дальше формы логина не пускает), но это нормально для supermicro.

Подскажите куда копать, BIOS сбросил в дефолт, на плате 2 диода (power и bmc/ipmi) и оба в статусе "OK" согласно мануалу.